# Using a toggle to turn off all other active classes on separate divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a small issue getting a toggle to work in a particle way, for all I know it can't be done using a toggle which is why I'm writing on here to see if someone can show me the best method. So at the moment I have 3 divs all of which have onclick events, and each have a toggle css class. What I'm trying to achieve is when one is clicked if the others are active they return back to the previous class.

```js
function orgClick(clicked_id) {
  var id = (clicked_id);
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('org_container_active');

}
```

```css
.org_container {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 6.25%;
  margin-right: 6.25%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.org_container_active {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 6.25%;
  margin-right: 6.25%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #2bbe43;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.org_name {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.org_logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.org_info {
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="org_container" id="org1" onclick="orgClick(this.id);">

  <div class="org_name">

    <p align="center">Org 1</p>

  </div>

  <div class="org_logo">

    <img src="http://server3.sulmaxcp.com/logo_unavailable.svg" width="100px" height="100px" ondragstart="return false;">

  </div>

  <div class="org_info">

    <p></p>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="org_container" id="org2" onclick="orgClick(this.id);">

  <div class="org_name">

    <p align="center">Org 2</p>

  </div>

  <div class="org_logo">

    <img src="http://server3.sulmaxcp.com/logo_unavailable.svg" width="100px" height="100px" ondragstart="return false;">

  </div>

  <div class="org_info">

    <p></p>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="org_container" id="org3" onclick="orgClick(this.id);">

  <div class="org_name">

    <p align="center">Org 3</p>

  </div>

  <div class="org_logo">

    <img src="http://server3.sulmaxcp.com/logo_unavailable.svg" width="100px" height="100px" class="noselect">

  </div>

  <div class="org_info">

    <p></p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll()` lets you search for all elements that match a CSS selector. You can use it to deactivate all active containers:

```
for (let div of document.querySelectorAll('.org_container_active')) {
    div.classList.remove('org_container_active');
}
```

Comment: How would I use this so that it prevents the clicked on div from being set back as well, as of course the div that is clicked I would want it to be the active.

Comment: Use `classList.add()` instead of `classList.toggle()` on the div that you want to set as active. You might want to check the full documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Is there a way to simply exclude an element using its id as I can use the `(this.id)` to work out which has been clicked

Comment: You can add `if (div === this) continue;` in the loop I wrote in my answer to skip the clicked div.